# PHP remove all html but comments

Tags: php, html, comments

How would I remove all of a an html input but comments? For example:
This `<html><body><!-- hello paragraph --><p>hello</p></body></html>`
Would turn into this: This `<!-- hello paragraph -->`

How would I do this? Thanks!

Edit: I know you can do stuff like this with regular expressions, But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing HTML, I'd extract all comments using:

```
preg_match_all('#(<!--.*?-->)#s', '<html><body><!-- hello paragraph --><p>hello</p></body></html>', $m);
```

Comment: I believe ths approach would be more robust than trying to identify non-comments.  It also wouldn't have the drawback that HTML tags inside comments would be mungled or removed.

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed a bit more complex, but doable with regular expressions:

```
$text = preg_replace('~<(?!!--)/?\w[^>]*(?<!--)>~', "", $text);
```

This works on your example, but can fail for others. Amusingly it also removes HTML tags from within comments.

```
$regex = '~
    <             # opening html bracket
    (?!!--)       # negative assertion, no "!--" may follow
    /?\w          # tags must start with letter or optional /
    [^>]*         # matches html tag innards
    (?<!--)       # lookbehind assertion, no "--" before closing >
    >             # closing bracket
 ~x'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo="<html><body><!-- hello paragraph --><p>hello</p></body></html>";
preg_match('/(\<|<)!--(\s*.*?\s*)--(\>|>)/m',$foo,$result);
print_r($result);
```